# Use multiple canvas URLs in one Facebook app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to host my web app on different domains. But I will receive errors like:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

However it seems I can only set one canvas URL and secure canvas URL in my Facebook settings page. Is it possible to host my web app on different domains? Thank you very much!

Comment: You would either need 2 separate apps, or you could use the application access token to programatically change the canvas URL's when triggered by a certain event.  Facebook will not allow more than one domain/url for a canvas app.

Answer (score 0):

If you can host a single php file (although it doesn't contain php at all, only javascript) on a SSL host you can do it. I wrote a [blog post](http://bit.ly/1wYHEhN) on how I did it using 2 app sharing the same canvas url.

A SSL host is mandatory for this to work. Also shared certificates work.

Short story long in the index.php file you need to:

```
var urlString=document.referrer;

var pageNameN = "?p="; //this is specific to the first application

var pageNameZ = "?url=";// this is specific to the second application


var indexN = urlString.indexOf(pageNameN);// and get its index.

var indexZ = urlString.indexOf(pageNameZ);// and get its index.


if(indexN != -1){
  var resN = urlString.substring(indexN);
  location.href = "https://FIRST_APPLICATION_URL/"+resN; }

else {  
if(indexZ != -1){
    var resZ = urlString.substring(indexZ);
    location.href = "https://SECOND_APPLICATION_URL"+resZ; }

}
```

You catch the request and than split it depending on the requesting url.

In the post you also find the index.php file I used in my case you can download, too.